# Javascript - CSS, visibility onclick

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

I am very new to Javascript. I have been looking into using Javascript to edit css style properties. I have searched the web and looked at a lot of different problems. Even with all of that, it is probably my inexperience as to why I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. What adds to the problem is that there are so many ways to do this. Anyway here are the specifics.

**What I want it to do:**
When someone clicks on the link in the code, I want the hidden DIV (which will just be near the top of my  waiting to be called on) to have its visibility switched to visible so as to create a new layer on the page.

**My code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function newwindow() {
                var showme = document.getelementbyid("testing");
                showme.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="newwindow()">Show me my hidden layer</a>
        <div id="testing" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: 50%; top: 50%;
    border: 1px solid darkblue; width: 400px; height: 300px; line-height: 300px;     
    text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -150px; margin-left: -200px; background: lightgray">HELLO!!!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I know there are a lot of ways to do this. But can someone show me what to tweak in the code I gave to make the way I am writing this work? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: You should use jQuery, it's a fantastic javascript library. http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `document.getElementById` not `document.getelementbyid`

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ecixeh/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Didn't realize Javascript was case sensitive.

Comment: @user1935137, how about setting this as the correct answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script language="javascript">
                function newwindow() {
                    var showme = document.getElementById("testing");
                    showme.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a href="#" onclick="newwindow()">Show me my hidden layer</a>
            <div id="testing" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: 50%; top: 50%;
        border: 1px solid darkblue; width: 400px; height: 300px; line-height: 300px;     
        text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: -150px; margin-left: -200px; background: lightgray">HELLO!!!</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```